# arduino nodemcu error compiling for board esp32

Tags: arduino, pyserial, esp32

when compiling a code in Arduino Idea get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/2.6.1/esptool.py", line 37, in 
    import serial
ImportError: No module named serial

exit status 1
Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.

Comment: Compile errors are difficult to diagnose without at least some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should install serial package.
use this code:

```
# For debian base linux
sudo apt-get install python-serial
# For Centos
sudo yum install python3-serial
# For Fedora
sudo dnf install python3-serial
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

This worked for me. I am using a Linux Machine.